# How do I get a multiline awk script running in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, github, yaml

To start this script is running it a Github workflow, using shell bash, yaml truncated for readability. I've tried a number of things to make it work as multiline, so I can have comments.

```bsh
  set -x
  set -e
  AWK_SOURCE=$( cat <<- AWK
  '
    {
      if ( $1 !~ /delete/ # ensure we are not trying to process deleted files
      && $4 !~ /theme.puml|config.puml/ # do not try to process our theme or custom config
      && $4 ~ /.puml/ ) # only process puml files
      { printf "%s ", $4 } # only print the file name and strip newlines for spaces
    }
    END { print "" } # ensure we do print a newline at the end
  '
  AWK
  )
  GIT_OUTPUT=`git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --summary ${GITHUB_SHA}`
  AWK_OUPUT=`echo $GIT_OUTPUT | awk -F' ' $AWK_SOURCE`
  echo "::set-output name=files::$GIT_OUTPUT"
  set +e
  set +x
```

this is my current error

If I run it as a single line, it works fine

```bsh
git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --summary HEAD | awk -F' ' '{ if ( $1 !~ /delete/ && $4 !~ /theme.puml|config.puml/ && $4 ~ /.puml/ ) { printf "%s ", $4 } } END { print "" }'
```

this is the output/error I'm currently getting, I've gotten different ones.

```
shell: /usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc -e -o pipefail {0}
+ set -e
++ cat
+ AWK_SOURCE=''\''
  {
    if (  !~ /delete/ # ensure we are not trying to process deleted files
    &&  !~ /theme.puml|config.puml/ # do not try to process our theme or custom config
    &&  ~ /.puml/ ) # only process puml files
    { printf "%s ",  } # only print the file name and strip newlines for spaces
  }
  END { print "" } # ensure we do print a newline at the end
'\'''
++ git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --summary 6c72c8a8dabf19ae2439ee506b9a4a636027193e
+ GIT_OUTPUT=' create mode 100644 .config/plantuml/config.puml
 create mode 100644 .config/plantuml/theme.puml
 delete mode 100644 config.puml
 create mode 100644 docs/README.md
 create mode 100644 docs/domain-model/README.md
 create mode 100644 docs/domain-model/user.md
 create mode 100644 docs/domain-model/user.puml
 delete mode 100644 theme.puml
 delete mode 100644 user.puml
 delete mode 100644 user.svg'
++ echo create mode 100644 .config/plantuml/config.puml create mode 100644 .config/plantuml/theme.puml delete mode 100644 config.puml create mode 100644 docs/README.md create mode 100644 docs/domain-model/README.md create mode 100644 docs/domain-model/user.md create mode 100644 docs/domain-model/user.puml delete mode 100644 theme.puml delete mode 100644 user.puml delete mode 100644 user.svg
++ awk '-F ' \' '{' if '(' '!~' /delete/ '#' ensure we are not trying to process deleted files '&&' '!~' '/theme.puml|config.puml/' '#' do not try to process our theme or custom config '&&' '~' /.puml/ ')' '#' only process puml files '{' printf '"%s' '",' '}' '#' only print the file name and strip newlines for spaces '}' END '{' print '""' '}' '#' ensure we do print a newline at the end \'
awk: cmd. line:1: '
awk: cmd. line:1: ^ invalid char ''' in expression
+ AWK_OUPUT=
```

how can I retain my multiline awk with comments?

Comment: copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net and it'll tell about some of the issues with it. Why are you trying to save your awk script in a variable?

Comment: @EdMorton that was just one of my attempts to solve this problem, I found that suggestion via the google, on stackoverflow, and I think some other stack exchange.

Comment: If you got an answer to your question then see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for what to do next.

Answer (score 2):

Your main issue is that the `awk` code isn't quoted, which makes the shell replace things like `$4` in the code.  To protect the code from the shell, make sure that the here-document is quoted.  You get a quoted here-document by enclosing the starting delimiting word in quotes, as in `<<'AWK'` or `<<"AWK"`, or by escaping it as `<<\AWK`.

Here's a rewrite of your script the way I would write it:

```bsh
git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --summary "$GITHUB_SHA" |
awk '
    $1 !~ /^delete/ && $4 !~ /(theme|config)\.puml$/ && $4 ~ /\.puml$/ {
        name[++n] = $4
    }
    END {
        $0 = ""
        for (i in name) $i = name[i]
        printf "::set-output name=files::%s\n", $0
    }'
```

Note that I'm not storing intermediate data in variables.  Doing so is inefficient (you may not know *how much* data you need to store in a variable) and prone to making quoting mistakes and instead spitting values on whitespaces and invoking filename globbing.  Your use of `$GIT_OUTPUT` and `$AWK` without quoting is problematic in this respect, and `echo $GIT_OUTPUT` is particularly troublesome since `echo` may modify the data if it contains backslashes, depending on the configuration of the shell.

About quoting: See [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)

I'm using the standard `pattern { action }` syntax in the script to build up an array, `name`, of the strings that you want to parse out.  In the `END` block, I create an output record, `$0`, that I output with a prefix that you used `echo` to output.

You could also do it like this, which leaves you a bit more room for comments:

```bsh
git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --summary "$GITHUB_SHA" |
awk '
    $1 ~ /^delete/ {
        # skip these
        next
    }
    $4 ~ /(theme|config)\.puml$/ {
        # and these...
        next
    }
    $4 ~ /\.puml$/ {
        # pick out filename (we assume no whitespace in filenames)
        name[++n] = $4
    }
    END {
        $0 = ""
        for (i in name) $i = name[i]
        printf "::set-output name=files::%s\n", $0
    }'
```

If you want to insist on having the `awk` source code in a here-document, I'd do it like this:

```bsh
awk_script=$(mktemp) || exit 1
trap 'rm -f "$awk_script"' EXIT

cat <<'AWK_CODE' >"$awk_script"
$1 !~ /^delete/ && $4 !~ /(theme|config)\.puml$/ && $4 ~ /\.puml$/ {
    name[++n] = $4
}
END {
    $0 = ""
    for (i in name) $i = name[i]
    printf "::set-output name=files::%s\n", $0
}
AWK_CODE

git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --summary "$GITHUB_SHA" |
awk -f "$awk_script"
```

I.e., save the `awk` script to a temporary file that is invoked using `awk -f` later, and removed at the end of the script (here, using a `trap`).  But for such a short `awk` program, I see no added benefit of doing this compared with using the script in a single-quoted string as shown first. It's messy and contains a lot of *extra commands* just for maintenance, apart from the two central commands that needs to be executed.

Comment: why is the for loop better?

Comment: @xenoterracide Sorry, what `for` loop? You mean the one in the `awk` code? It's just a way to turn an array into a record for printing with the value of `OFS` as the delimiter (a space by default), so that you don't have to think about inserting spaces manually or when to output a newline at the end.

Comment: yeah, the one in the awk code. Ok.

Answer (score 2):

Put your code in functions, not variables, something like this (untested and still room for improvement):

```
set -x
set -e
do_awk() {
    awk '
        ($1 !~ /delete/) &&                 # ensure we are not trying to process deleted files
        ($4 !~ /theme.puml|config.puml/) && # do not try to process our theme or custom config
        ($4 ~ /.puml/) {                    # only process puml files
            printf "%s ", $4                # only print the file name and strip newlines for spaces
        }
        END { print "" }                    # ensure we do print a newline at the end
    ' "${@:--}"
}
GIT_OUTPUT=$(git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --summary "$GITHUB_SHA")
AWK_OUPUT=$(printf '%s\n' "$GIT_OUTPUT" | do_awk)
echo "::set-output name=files::$GIT_OUTPUT"
set +e
set +x
```

Comment: hmm... I had problem because of the comments with the if, that no one mentioned, I'm curious though as to why your awk doesn't need an if, and what the "$@:--" does, and why I should put it in a function.

Comment: An awk script is made up of a list of `<condition> { <action> }` statements where the action is executed if the condition is true. You CAN alternatively write `<condition1> { if (<condition2>) <action> }` since the default `condition1` is `true` but that's just not necessary. The comments in your "if" weren't a problem best I can tell (you didn't say what problem you had with them) but white space matters in awk so you can't write a condition as `foo \n&& bar`, it has to be `foo &&\n bar`.

Comment: `"${@:--}"` in a shell script or function means "read the args as files if present, otherwise read stdin" so you can call a script/function as `script file` or `cat file | script` or `script` then type input. Encapsulating code is the reason functions exist (and aliases for trivial cases). Variables are for holding values.

Comment: I was getting syntax errors where the comments were in the if

Comment: Ah, I see - that'd probably be because you were passing your variable to awk unquoted (`awk -F' ' $AWK_SOURCE` instead of `awk -F' ' "$AWK_SOURCE"`) and so it was getting converted by the shell from multi-line to a single line and therefore every part of the script after the first `#` was treated as within the comment that started as that point and so resulting in half a script. I expect shellcheck.net (see [my first comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/638803/how-do-i-get-a-multiline-awk-script-running-in-bash/638821?noredirect=1#comment1196982_638803) warned you about that.

Comment: even after I got rid of the variable.

Comment: Then I have no idea what code you were executing or what the specific error message you got was and so I can't help you debug it. Don't just paste the error, also paste the code that resulted in that error and be sure to put it in your question, don't post it in a comment.

Comment: yeah, I know, you were too fast for me, I was adding "I'll see if I can repro later, and paste the error." ;)

Comment: Also make sure to run it through shellcheck first so we don't have to look at it if the tool tells you what the issue is.

Comment: Also - if it's going to be another case where you're storing the awk script in a variable, I personally wouldn't want to even look at that to try to guess where the issues might be between what the shell is doing with it when defined vs when used and what awk is doing with it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way (in terms of readability and maintainability) to my mind is to send your `awk` script to a temporary file to then be sourced by `awk`:

```
awksrc=$(mktemp) || exit 1
cat << 'EOF' > "${awksrc}"
{
  if ( $1 !~ /delete/ # ensure we are not trying to process deleted files
       && $4 !~ /theme.puml|config.puml/ # do not try to process our theme or custom config
       && $4 ~ /.puml/ 
  ) # only process puml files
      { printf "%s ", $4 } # only print the file name and strip newlines for spaces
}
END { print "" } # ensure we do print a newline at the end
EOF
echo "$GIT_OUTPUT" | awk -f "${awksrc}" 
rm -f "${awksrc}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used GitHub Workflow, but [the documentation says](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsrun) you can use a custom shell. It would seem if you say:

```
steps:
  - name: process puml files
    run: <your awk script here>
    shell: awk -f {0}
```

or some permutation thereof, you should be able to run the raw awk script without the shell shenanigans.