# deduplicate mostly negated awk

Tags: awk

do not repeat yourself!, lol, ok, I'm trying to see if I can consolidate my 2 github workflows awk sources into 1. I tried a few things, but for some reason I kept ending up with weird column stuff. retrospectively I might have been assigning not comparing variables. I decided not to polute the question with broken code.

awk is being run as `git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --name-status HEAD | awk -f .github/files/changed.awk`, no options. The output of `git diff-tree` looks something like this

```
( cat << EOF
A       .config/plantuml/theme.puml
M       .github/workflows/main.yml
M       .github/workflows/plantuml.yml
M       README.md
A       app/gradle.lockfile
A       authn/gradle.lockfile
A       docs/README.md
A       docs/domain-model/README.md
A       docs/domain-model/user.md
A       docs/domain-model/user.puml
A       docs/domain-model/foo.puml
M       settings.gradle.kts
D       user.puml
D       foo.puml
EOF
) | awk -f file.awk
```

These are what I came up with.

```c
$2 ~ /\.puml$/ &&
$2 !~ /(theme|config)\.puml$/ &&
$1 !~ /^D$/ {
  changed[++n]=$2
}
END {
  for ( i in changed ) result = result " " changed[i]
  printf "::set-output name=changed-files::%s\n", result
  printf "::warning::changed-files %s\n", result
}
```

outputs

```
::set-output name=changed-files:: docs/domain-model/user.puml docs/domain-model/foo.puml
::warning::changed-files docs/domain-model/user.puml docs/domain-model/foo.puml
```

```c
$2 ~ /\.puml$/ &&
$2 !~ /(theme|config)\.puml$/ &&
$1 ~ /^D$/ {
  split($2, fn, ".")
  changed[++n]=fn[1] ".svg"
}
END {
  for ( i in changed ) result = result " " changed[i]
  printf "::set-output name=removed-files::%s\n", result
  printf "::warning::removed-files %s\n", result
}
```

outputs

```
::set-output name=removed-files:: user.svg foo.svg
::warning::removed-files  user.svg foo.svg
```

Here's the [current workflow file](https://github.com/xenoterracide/iw-ppm-backend/blob/e4e5baeef01863c1a104d90ac0fb94e59834be94/.github/workflows/plantuml.yml) if that helps. note: the change to `awk -f` is being made in a currently broken branch, which I'll delete and squash when finished.

the goal is to get output **similar** to the following. I **don't care** about the order of lines, and the whitespace within the list only matters so much as it can be passed to `git add`, `git rm` and `plantuml` on the shell.

```
# adding empty lines between just for readability here, comments do nott matter either
::set-output name=changed-files:: docs/domain-model/user.puml docs/domain-model/foo.puml
::warning::changed-files docs/domain-model/user.puml docs/domain-model/foo.puml

::set-output name=removed-files:: user.svg foo.svg
::warning::removed-files  user.svg foo.svg
```

How would you deduplicate and improve it?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/638805/116858

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with some improvements and deduplicate two parts into one.

```
$2 ~ /\.puml$/ && $2 !~ /(theme|config)\.puml$/ \
{ if($1 !~ /^D$/) { result1= (result1==""? "" : result1 " ") $2 } else {
      split($2, fn, ".")
      result2=(result2==""? "" : result2 " ") fn[1] ".svg"
  }
}
END {
  printf "::set-output name=files::%s\n::warning::%s\n", result1, result1
  printf "::set-output name=files::%s\n::warning::%s\n", result2, result2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you have **one** input (or file, the result of git)

```
A       .config/plantuml/theme.puml
M       .github/workflows/main.yml
M       .github/workflows/plantuml.yml
M       README.md
A       app/gradle.lockfile
A       authn/gradle.lockfile
A       docs/README.md
A       docs/domain-model/README.md
A       docs/domain-model/user.md
A       docs/domain-model/user.puml
A       docs/domain-model/foo.puml
M       settings.gradle.kts
D       user.puml
D       foo.puml
```

and **two** awk scripts that do similar (but distinct) actions on this input.

I assume that your goal is to reduce (as possible) the actions of this scripts.

The first two lines are exactly equal:

```
$2 ~ /\.puml$/ &&
$2 !~ /(theme|config)\.puml$/
```

After that, one script takes action on `$2` being **not** `D` (I assume that means deleted). The other script takes action on the complement, `$2` being `D`. That could be coded as:

```
{ if ( $1 ~ /^[D]$/ ) then { print "Deleted" } else { print "Changed" } }
```

Or, if you want a more granular selection:

```
{ if ( $1 ~ /^[D]$/  ) then { print "Deleted" } 
  if ( $1 ~ /^[MA]$/ ) then { print "Changed" } }
```

Storing each file in one array is not really needed as what you need is an space separated list of files.

That could be done inside the loop for each input line (less memory, faster):

```
{ if ( $1 ~ /^[D]$/ ) then { deleted = deleted " " $2 } 
  if ( $1 ~ /^[A]$/ ) then { changed = changed " " $2 } }
```

Of course, the match could be an exact string instead of a regex (faster) and you also need to extract the filename without extension in the changed case:

```
{ if ( $1 == "D" ) then { deleted = deleted " " $2 } 
  if ( $1 == "A" ) then { sub( /\.[^.]+$/, "", $2 ) ; 
                          changed = changed " " $2 ".svg"
                        }
}
```

A shell script to test all ideas could be:

```
#!/bin/bash

a='\
A       .config/plantuml/theme.puml
M       .github/workflows/main.yml
M       .github/workflows/plantuml.yml
M       README.md
A       app/gradle.lockfile
A       authn/gradle.lockfile
A       docs/README.md
A       docs/domain-model/README.md
A       docs/domain-model/user.md
A       docs/domain-model/user.puml
A       docs/domain-model/foo.puml
M       settings.gradle.kts
D       user.puml
D       foo.puml
'

printf '%s\n' "$a" | awk '
      $2  ~ /\.puml$/ &&
      $2 !~ /(theme|config)\.puml$/ {  
             if ( $1 == "D" ) { deleted = deleted " " $2 }
             if ( $1 == "A" ) { sub(/\.[^.]+$/, "", $2);
                                changed = changed " " $2 ".svg"
             }
      }
      END {
             printf "::set-output name=removed-files::%s\n", deleted
             printf "::warning::removed-files %s\n", deleted
             printf "::set-output name=changed-files::%s\n", changed
             printf "::warning::changed-files %s\n", changed
      }
    '
```